# Setting up names for querystring and header in APIGateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

here is an example how i am setting up my stack. I am posting only bit of this, rest assured, the stack is working fine.

Question i want to ask that, how can i specific `queryString` name at url level. Right now on AWS console (Web UI), it displays `{orderId}` but i want it to display something else. How can i modify that?

Also, it displays `{orderId}` for `HEADERS` box on AWS UI. I want to change that too.

```
OrdersPathResource:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Resource"
    Properties:
        RestApiId:
            Ref: "XYZApi"
        ParentId: !GetAtt [XYZApi, RootResourceId]
        PathPart: "orders"

OrdersIdPathResource:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
    Properties:
        RestApiId:
            Ref: "XYZApi"
        ParentId:
            Ref: "OrdersPathResource"
        PathPart: "{ordersId}"

StatusPathResource:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
    Properties:
        RestApiId:
            Ref: "XYZApi"
        ParentId:
            Ref: "OrdersIdPathResource"
        PathPart: "status"

GetOrdersShipmentStatusMethod:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Method"
    Properties:
        ApiKeyRequired: true
        AuthorizationType: "AWS_IAM"
        HttpMethod: "GET"
        ResourceId:
            Ref: "StatusPathResource"
        RestApiId:
            Ref: "XYZApi"
        Integration:
            Type: "AWS_PROXY"
            IntegrationHttpMethod: "POST"
            Uri: !Join ["", ["arn:aws:apigateway:", !Ref "AWS::Region", ":lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/",!GetAtt GetOrdersShipmentStatusLambdaFunction.Arn, "/invocations"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

From your CloudFormation template snippet, you are using a Lambda Proxy integration, so API Gateway will not let you set up the parameter mappings to your integration. But if you want to have the request parameters on the method side, you can change your method to something like,

```
    GetOrdersShipmentStatusMethod:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Method"
    Properties:
        ApiKeyRequired: true
        AuthorizationType: "AWS_IAM"
        HttpMethod: "GET"
        ResourceId:
            Ref: "StatusPathResource"
        RestApiId:
            Ref: "XYZApi"
        RequestParameters:
            method.request.header.headerName: false
            method.request.querystring.querystringName: false
        Integration:
            Type: "AWS_PROXY"
            IntegrationHttpMethod: "POST"
            Uri: !Join ["", ["arn:aws:apigateway:", !Ref "AWS::Region", ":lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/",!GetAtt GetOrdersShipmentStatusLambdaFunction.Arn, "/invocations"]]
```